# Linux kernel: is a re-assigned page frame cleared?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, paging

When a process ends, the Linux kernel can re-assign the user-space page frames (the pages in physical memory) to the user-space pages (in virtual memory) of another process.

Are the page frames cleared before the re-assignment? Otherwise old content might be visible to another process, I can't imagine that this would be allowed. One situation would be assigning page frames to a growing heap where old content may be visible in allocated memory.

Comment: Yes, page contents are initialized before being mapped to a process. For example, if the GNU memory allocator (in glibc) gets more memory with `mmap`, that memory will be zeroed. I think it starts off as a "Copy On Write" (COW) reference to a special "all zero" page that gets duplicated to a normal page when the process writes to the page.

Comment: This is why your userspace library may not return pages to the system on free, but keep them for subsequent allocations.  It saves the syscall and clearing the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "re-assigned" physical memory is cleared, but how and when exactly is a bit tricky. The page is not cleared right away, but rather on the first *write* page fault after another process maps it.

Assuming an anonymous "zero-fill on demand" page:

1. User program A is using a memory page with physical address PA.
2. User program A terminates execution, kernel claims memory back, *physical memory contents are still unchanged*.
3. User program B (or even A again, doesn't matter) starts and requests a memory page.
4. Kernel creates a virtual mapping for the requested page.
5. User program B writes to the mapping, causing a write page fault.
6. Kernel allocates memory, and gets a physical page with physical address PA, same as point 1.
7. Kernel clears the page (zeroing-out any previous content) and updates the virtual mapping accordingly (page tables, etc.).

So the actual clearing happens "lazily", potentially a lot later (step 7) than when the memory was released and claimed back by the kernel (step 2).

**NOTE**: what happens for the first ***read*** page fault on a newly created anonymous mapping is quite a different story. The kernel always keeps a physical page that is completely zeroed out (called the "zero page"), and creates a virtual mapping to this page. This happens for every process that needs it, so the zero page is mapped a lot of times in multiple VMAs of different processes. This is done for performance (no need to zero-out anything) and to save memory (no need to allocate a new page until a write occurs).

---

Regarding the write fault, which is when the page is actually cleared, one of the possible code paths in the kernel is:

- *Arch-specific page fault handler* (code should be in `arch/XXX/mm/fault.c`)
- [`handle_mm_fault()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/mm/memory.c#L4763)
- [`__handle_mm_fault()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/mm/memory.c#L4607)
- [`handle_pte_fault()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/mm/memory.c#L4503)
- [`do_anonymous_page()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/mm/memory.c#L3714) (assuming an anonymous mapping)
- [`alloc_zeroed_user_highpage_movable()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/mm/memory.c#L3767)
- Some variant of `alloc_pages()` passing `__GFP_ZERO`
- [`clear_page()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/include/asm-generic/page.h#L28)
- Return allocated and zeroed page

Comment: Thanks a lot for the in-depth answer. Just one question: probably also a *read* attempt by program B causes a page fault and leads to an initialization of the page frame?

Comment: @Ralf no that's  a slightly different story. I edited the answer to add this info.