# Does paging allow process A to access process B memory?

Tags: linux, operating-system

Does OS clear the physical memory during paging ? If not, is it possible for a new virtual page to map to physical memory area that contains values from another program whose memory has been paged to hard drive?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103058/14772619) answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, kernel can freeing-up memory, adding it to the free list of pages.

Yes it's possible. But you can securely deleting data in ram.

See:
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/316.html

https://medium.com/the-infosec-journal/the-danger-of-storing-data-in-clear-text-in-main-memory-81fe9226ac94

https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=87152468#content/view/87152468